# Initialise DataFrame from numpy array with supplementary columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following bit of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A = ['red', 'blue']
B = range(2)
C = np.random.random((4,2,2))
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Color':np.repeat(A,2),'Trial':np.tile(B,2),'V0':C[:,0,0],'V1':C[:,0,1],
                  'V2':C[:,1,0], 'V3':C[:,1,1]})
df
```

Which outputs the following dataframe

```
>   Color Trial    V0          V1         V2          V3
> 0 red     0   0.726781    0.549726    0.053999    0.469885
> 1 red     1   0.609131    0.012120    0.587780    0.344290
> 2 blue    0   0.285235    0.491907    0.907871    0.549792
> 3 blue    1   0.646334    0.164288    0.029917    0.181290
```

I would like to avoid having to type out each entry of the numpy array if the size of the array grows so I came up with the following solution for larger arrays

```
A = ['red', 'blue']
B = range(2)
C = np.random.random((4,2,2))
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Color':np.repeat(A,2),'Trial':np.tile(B,2)})
_df = pd.DataFrame(C.reshape(4,4)).add_prefix('V')
df = pd.concat([df,_df],axis=1)
df
```

Which has the same output. My question is if there is a better way of doing this that doesn't involve creating a dataframe for each array I want to include and then concatenating them?

Comment: what step are you trying to avoid doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naw, seems like you've got your bases covered.... Here's a bit of cleanup though, using `DataFrame.assign`—

```
pd.DataFrame(C.reshape(4,4)).add_prefix('V')).assign(
    Color=A * len(A), Trial=np.tile(B, len(A))
)

         V0        V1        V2        V3 Color  Trial
0  0.625676  0.201339  0.873423  0.227824   red      0
1  0.202515  0.515637  0.344809  0.958107  blue      1
2  0.040853  0.682505  0.679995  0.104927   red      0
3  0.548399  0.315772  0.081189  0.282158  blue      1
```

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks! I realised that might be needed once I saw what Wen was getting at.

Comment: I ended up going with this one because it lets me get the naming of all the columns done as well, but both solutions are very good!

Answer (score 3):

From `MultiIndex`

```
pd.DataFrame(data=C.reshape(4,4), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([A,B])).add_prefix('V')


              V0        V1        V2        V3
red  0  0.625676  0.201339  0.873423  0.227824
     1  0.202515  0.515637  0.344809  0.958107
blue 0  0.040853  0.682505  0.679995  0.104927
     1  0.548399  0.315772  0.081189  0.282158
```

Comment: I like the way you think (-: